# How to remove "" in output list?

Tags: json

I used a command to get a list of IP from EC2.

The result so far i got is a list like this:

```
[
    "172.31.11.7",
    "172.31.48.141",
    "172.31.64.201",
    "172.31.64.149",
    "172.31.64.148",
    "172.31.64.111"
]
```

I want to get result as:

```
172.31.11.7
172.31.48.141
172.31.64.201
172.31.64.149
172.31.64.148
172.31.64.111
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
jq -r '.[]' file
```

---

Using `egrep`:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file
```

or

```
egrep -o '([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+' file
```

---

Using `grep`:

```
grep -o '[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' file
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is a JSON array.  Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the elements:

```
$ jq -r '.[]' file
172.31.11.7
172.31.48.141
172.31.64.201
172.31.64.149
172.31.64.148
172.31.64.111
```

Answer (score 1):

using AWK,

```
  awk -F '"' '{if (NF==3) print $2}' file
```

- using `“` as a delimiter
- printing second filed `$2`
- `NF==3` if the maximum number of field is equal to 3

Answer (score 1):

For that sample,

```
cut -d'"' -sf2
```

would be enough. It returns the part of the line between the first and second `"` occurrence and (with `-s`) discards the lines that don't contain any `"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\" 'NF>1{print $2}' file
```